VSCode clang-format command keeps not available
I am running VSCode 1.95.0 on Win10 64 applying Platformio for programming eg. ESP8266.
I want to use the formatting feature of clang.
Downloaded clang+llvm-18.1.8-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.tar.xz and extracted it to folder C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM.The clang executables are in the subfolder /bin.
When trying to format I get following message:
The 'c::\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\bin\clang-format.exe' command is not available.  Please check your clang-format.executable user setting and ensure it is installed.
The clang-format extension v1.9.0  by Xaver is installed.
See settings.json
{
"launch": {
    "configurations": [
    
    ]
},
"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark - C++",
"[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true
},
"editor.defaultFormatter": "xaver.clang-format",
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never",
"clang-format.executable": "c::\\Program Files (x86)\\LLVM\\bin\\clang-format.exe"
}
}

I created a clang-format configuration file that I placed in the src folder of the project named clang-format:
{BasedOnStyle:   Microsoft
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: true
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
}

putting the clang-format file to other folders did not help.
Which folder is the right one for this configuration file. In front ot he filename is a purple excalmation mark that indicates tha the file is a yml file. Is this correct?
How to get it working?
Reading docs, checking subject on Youtube videos and tutorials, searching the web.

you have an extra colon in your path, c:: should be c:

Solved.   Corrected to
"clang-format.executable": "c:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\bin\clang-format.exe"

Change that line, you have a mistake.
"clang-format.executable": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LLVM\\bin\\clang-format.exe"

